# Error when executing kerasR: "keras not available"

Tags: python, r, keras

I cannot run `kerasR::keras_init()` as it gives the following error:

```
keras not available
See reticulate::use_python() to set python path, 
then use `kerasR::keras_init() to retry
```

I tried to set the PATH using `use_python()` initially which didn't help.

The following configuration observed in my conda env (which shows existence of keras):

```
python:         C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/python.exe
libpython:      C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/python38.dll
pythonhome:     C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3
version:        3.8.5 (default, Aug  5 2020, 09:44:06) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
Architecture:   64bit
numpy:          C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/Lib/site-packages/numpy
numpy_version:  1.19.1
keras:          C:\PROGRA~3\ANACON~1\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.p

python versions found: 
 C:/Users/janak/.conda/envs/r-reticulate/python.exe 
 C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/python.exe
```

Also, in python (from conda env) `import keras` gives the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras'
```

But, `from tensorflow import keras` works.

Please explain this error. I think both are originated to same issue.